# Haskell accessors for non-existing records

Tags: haskell, accessor

I am learning Haskell and I am currently discovering 'accessors' for data members.
Let's assume I have some dummy 2D vertex information, one type that has some color, the other than has some texture coordinate (tc):

```
data SVertex = VertexC (Float, Float) Int
         | VertexTC (Float, Float) (Float, Float)
         deriving(Show)
```

One tedious way to create accessors to records is to write functions with patterns:

```
position (VertexC (x,y) c ) = (x,y)
position (VertexTC (x,y) c ) = (x,y)
tc (VertexTC _ tc) = tc
color :: SVertex -> Int
color (VertexC _ c) = c
```

Now, a positive feature is that I could add accessors ('color' and 'tc') for the ones that don't have 'color' or 'tc' :

```
position (VertexC (x,y) c ) = (x,y)
position (VertexTC (x,y) c ) = (x,y) -- no header, here... still works
tc (VertexTC _ tc) = tc
tc (VertexC _ _) = (0,0) -- to returns something even if the field doesn't exist
color :: SVertex -> Int
color (VertexC _ c) = c
color (VertexTC _ _) = 0 -- return something even if field doesn't exist
```

It allows me to give default 0 values to the vertices that don't have any texture-coords or color 0 to the vertices that don't have color...
All good...

Now, my question: I am currently reading that there is a nice way to give accessor names right into the data declaration.
In my case here is what I would get (using 'prime' to avoid name conflict):

```
data SVertex' = VertexC' {
    position'   :: (Float, Float),
    color'      :: Int
    }
    | VertexTC' {
    position'   :: (Float, Float),
    tc'         :: (Float, Float)
    } deriving(Show)
```

This allows me to reach the same goal: the "position' ", "tc' " and "color' " accessors are created for me!

*However*: I didn't find a way to give default accessor for the fields that don't exist. For example when requesting for tc on 'VertexC'; or requesting color on VertexTC...
On the first approach, I could make it happen. In this convenient second approach, I fear it is not possible.
When I try to add other function pattern like

```
color' (VertexTC' _ _) = 0
```

the compiler tells me *"Multiple declarations of ‘color’ etc."*. And it seems like it is because this second declaration is not done following the previous implicit one created by the compiler...

Do you know a workaround ?

Comment: I don't believe this is possible. Haskell records are a bit of a pain point in general (especially the fact they are partial, which is sort of what you are getting at). If you are interested in records, you will probably end up checking out [`lens`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) at some point (where this partiality is dealt with using a `Prism` abstraction).

Comment: This is not possible, but it is also an indicator of non-idiomatic Haskell. Consider making heavier use of pattern matching when you use `SVertex` instances to deal with these defaults, rather than making a global rule (the latter approach feels very Java-esque).

Comment: I didn't realize accessing 'records' are so flawed in Haskell. Thanks for the confirmation on how I should be aware of this.
It seems like some people are trying to improve things in this scope: http://nikita-volkov.github.io/record/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you have just found out, records don't mix very well with sum types (that is, types with multiple constructors), as they lead to unpleasant partial accessors that you can't get rid of. One alternative is using a sum type only for the fields that actually require it, rather than making `SVertex` as a whole a sum type. That way, you get as many nice accessors as possible while avoiding the partial ones.

```
data VertexPaint = VertexC Int | VertexTC (Float, Float)
    deriving (Show)

data SVertex = SVertex
    { position :: (Float, Float)
    , paintjob :: VertexPaint
    } deriving (Show)
```

If you want a `color` function, you still have to define it separately, as in your first attempt. (Here I will use a `Maybe Int` result, as that is more often than not a safer bet than returning an arbitrary default.)

```
color :: SVertex -> Maybe Int
color v = case paintjob v of
    VertexC c -> Just c
    VertexTC _ -> Nothing
```

As Alec suggests, the [*lens*](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/lens) library provides plenty of tools to deal with this sort of situation in more convenient ways. In any case, the types defined in this answer would work well with *lens*.